# How do I count multiple instances of the same value within an array?

Tags: java

I have a homework problem where I am creating a POS for a dog rental company. There is one section where I need to provide a report showing the number of times each breed of dog was rented. This data is stored within an array called transactionList. I have already sorted the dog transactions by breed but cannot figure out how to count the number of times each breed was counted. How would I go about implementing this sort of count?

Comment: Please add some code to make it more clear what you are asking!

Comment: Please show code, i.e. how does your transactionList looks like etc?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I would guess that you just want to have a map. Iterate through the list, and for each element of the list, check if it has been added to the map. If it has, iterate the value, otherwise, add an entry to the map with 1 as the value and the element name as the key.

Comment: If you have an array sorted by breed, there is no need for a map. Just  initialize a counter and step through the array, incrementing the counter if the breed is the same, and reporting the n umber (and resetting the counter) if the breed changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < transactionList.length; i++) {

    if(transactionList[i].equals("Beagle")) {
        count++;
    }

}
System.out.print("The beagle was rented " + count + "times.");
```

This is performing a linear search through the array and counting how many times a breed of a dog appeared in the transaction history.

Tip:
Show us some code so we understand how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know all the breeds, and you want to avoid advanced concepts like maps, here is the simplest way I can think of (note that you don't even need to sort transactionList):

```
String[] breeds = { "Poodle", "Labrador", "Beagle"};
int[] counts = new int[breeds.length];
for(Dog dog : transactionList) {
   for(int index = 0; index < breeds.length; index++) {
      if(dog.getBreed().equals(breeds[index])) {
         counts[index] += 1; 
      }
   }
}
```

Afterwards, you have the Beagle count in the counts array at the same index the Beagle is in your breeds array.

Obviously, this is a lot of guesswork, and you have to adapt this to your code.